# Bootstrap "hidden-xs" not working + Unable to make sticky footer for small viewports

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a world of issues trying to make my footer stick to the bottom of the page on smaller viewports, so as a bandaid I was playing around with just hiding the div all together until I can get it sorted.

**The HTML**

```
<div class="sitefooter">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        code
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
        code
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
        code
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row top20">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-xs-6" style="text-align:center;">
        code
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6" style="text-align:right;">
        code
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I've tried adding xs-hidden to each col-md div, I tried wrapping the entire thing in xs-hidden, I tried picking just certain parts for testing and none of it yielded a hidden div in a tiny viewport.

I tested xs-hidden on a completely different element of the site and it worked fine but I can't make it work here.

**The CSS**

```
.sitefooter {
bottom: 0;
position:absolute;
background:url(../img/headerbg.png);
width: 100%;
height:287px;
padding-bottom:20px;
}

.sitefooter>.container>.row>.col-md-3>p, .sitefooter>.container>.row>.col-md-4>p, .sitefooter>.container>.row>.col-md-2>p {
font-size:14px;
padding-top:10px;
color:#CCC;
padding-bottom:15px;
}


.sitefooter>.container>.row>.col-md-3>h3, .sitefooter>.container>.row>.col-md-4>h3, .sitefooter>.container>.row>.col-md-2>h3 {
font-size:20px;
padding-top:20px;
color:#408af0;
}

.sitefooter>.container>.row>.col-md-3>a, .sitefooter>.container>.row>.col-md-4>a, .sitefooter>.container>.row>.col-md-2>a {
color:#999;
font-size:14px;
}

.sitefooter>.container>.row>.col-md-3>a:hover, .sitefooter>.container>.row>.col-md-4>a:hover, .sitefooter>.container>.row>.col-md-2>a:hover {
color:#fff;
font-size:14px;
}

.top20 { margin-top:20px; }
```

Ultimately, the desired state is a sticky footer on all view ports but this would be an OK compromise.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: sticky = `position:fixed`, use media queries if needed for smaller sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the default bootstrap breakpoints, you could just make use of media queries on the screen widths you're looking for. If you are looking to apply the changes to xs bootstrap screens, you could use the following media query

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
     // Code Here
}
```

If you want to make the footer stick to the bottom on xs screens, simply use:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

    .sitefooter {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
    }

}
```

If you want to hide the footer altogether on that same screen width, you can instead use:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

    .sitefooter {
        display: none;
    }

}
```

Sometimes it's easier to utilize media queries instead of the visibility classes that ship with bootstrap, mainly because it will provide you with a lot more customization.

Comment: Hi mate - thanks for the help!

I'm finding that the :fixed command is just affixing the footer to the bottom of the view port, rather than the page.

I'm thinking that my issue is more that the footer might be too large for xs screens and just not scaling down properly (or at all) so the footer is attaching properly but due to it being fixed height, the content is just too big.

Comment: If you want to fix it to the bottom of the page rather than the viewport, that gets a little trickier. Take a look at this for a little trick that can be used to solve that: [CSS-tricks sticky footer](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/) ...other than that, there isn't really a clean way of doing it without using JavaScript, etc

Comment: I've just finished testing my theory - turns out I am an idiot and didn't consider that my content was overflowing. I copied your @media query (shrunk it to 320) and change the font to xxem; and it's solved the issue.

Thanks for your help mate :)

Comment: Perfect! Glad I could help